# SP13 - How to set true value for sharepoint checkbox field

Tags: sharepoint-server, development

I want to set true or false value to sharepoint checkbox field with C# Server object model.

**This is my code:**

//SODigitalNationalMuseumFund(ChoiceField -> Yes/No)
                                        `addItem["SODigitalNationalMuseumFund"] = Convert.ToString(dRow[9]).Trim();`

How to do this? Thank you previously!

Comment: try setting "1" for true and "0" for false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a value to a choice field , this value should be in the range of choice column existing values so , Try this

```
string myChoice="True";

item["Choice Column"] = list.Fields["Choice Column"].GetFieldValue(myChoice);
```

Where `GetFieldValue()` matches an existing value in the choice column.

For more details check [Programmatically Setting the Value of a SharePoint Choice Column](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2012/10/programmatically-setting-the-value-of-a-sharepoint-choice-column-3/)